# Choosing multiple options from QGIS Check Box or Value Map for feature attribute?

Tags: qgis

I am presently working with some layers containing location data for plots/parcel data. Some of the parcels have multiple use types.

Is it possible to configure the Check Box or Value Map (widgets type) so that it can allow me/user to input/choose multiple options in cases where the parcel has more than one use type?

I am using QGIS 2.18

Comment: Is QGIS 2.18 mandatory ? If not, think to upgrade your version ! And for your question, look at the 1-n relations (it's available for 2.18) : https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=relation#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution like that:

- Create a CSV file which contains use types (`Parcel_Types.csv`).
  File content: (example)

  ```
  TYPE
  type1
  type2
  type3
  type4
  ```
- Add it using "Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer". Choose "No Geometry"
- Add `ParcelType` field to Parcel_Layer. Field type should be the same with types in CSV. That's, since `type1`, `type2`, etc are string, therefore, type of the field should be string (Text). If values are integer (for example: type code `1`, `2` instead of `type1`, `type2`) in CSV, then field type should be integer.
- Open "Layer Properties > Fields". Set options as in the image. (choose Parcel_Types table (comes from csv) as Layer, check "Allow multiple selections")

[image]

- Now you can make multiple selections for 'use types' of parcel in "Editing Mode".

[image]

Comment: Everything works just like you explained. Thank you very much Kadir. I tested using version 3.10.2. My primary need for multiple checks is with QField with which I also tested your answer. There a problem seems to arise with csv-format since it it is not supported. This can be bypassed by using a format which QField supports, like a shapefile for example and having that inside the mobile project as well.

Comment: Just tried your solution and it works.

Comment: I tried this and it works, my solution however requires inputting the value instead of activating/ticking, I write the number in the box. Any hints?