# Build Radio Button in QGIS Edit Widget Properties

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, fields-attributes, qgis-custom-widgets

My question is similar to [Choosing multiple options from QGIS Check Box or Value Map for feature attribute?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239348/how-to-choose-multiple-options-from-qgis-check-box-or-value-map-for-feature-attr)

I have 3 categories in a row, I want to make this selection in form of radio button so that selection can be made more than one.

Instead of using Value Map just like below, I want to display it using Radio Button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Radio button allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of mutually exclusive options, do you need check box?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom form using Qt Designer.  In designer you may tie a radio control to an field/attribute and use python to handle any control logic.

[QGIS Tips – Custom feature forms with Python logic](https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/)

I also presented how to do this in this conference presentation:

[Python + QGIS + Qt = Field Data Collection App](http://gis3.oit.ohio.gov/OGRIPWeb/OhioGIS/2017/Presentations/Tue_0910_T2.pdf)