# Value relation: Use multiselections together with auto completer

Tags: qgis-3, qfield

During fieldwork I want to select from 1 to up to 70ish species from a list of appr. 400 species.

The **value relation widget** works fine in both QGIS and QField.
This widget gives me the opportunity to "**Allow multiple selections**" which works fine on shorter lists, but not very convenient with 400 list-items. Also "**Use completer**" works fine, but only allowing *one* selection.

I was hoping for a combination of multiple selections and the completer:
Start typing the specie, choose from the drop down list, start typing a new specie and choose from the list and continue until all species in that particular location are recorded.

I had a look at [How to create a Value Map widget type to select multiple values (checklist) from the dropdown?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346634/how-to-create-a-value-map-widget-type-to-select-multiple-values-checklist-from?noredirect=1&lq=1)
However, this involves creating my own form (ui-file) which QField don't support AFAIK.

Anyone who knows if this is possible to achieve in QGIS using Autogenerate or Drag and drop designer in Attributes form and/or in QField?

I'm using QGIS 3.26 on Windows 10 and QField 2.1.4 on Android 10.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not possible in QField (and probably not in QGIS either) for time being.
Read more at [Use the new relation widget when allowMultiple is enabled](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/1436).

**UPDATE QGIS 3.30**: Multiselection and Completer is working: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/index.html#feature-multiple-selections-with-filtering-in-value-relation-widget