# Creating permanent dropdown lists in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, dropdownlist

I've had some success at creating the drop down lists for attributes in QGIS 3.16 using the Attribute Form option in Layer Properties, as shown here: [Creating a multiple select dropdown list in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306881/creating-a-multiple-select-dropdown-list-in-qgis)

My problem is that whenever I remove the layer and then bring it back into QGIS, my drop down lists are not an option in the attributes. They have gone.

Could anyone give guidance to how to make drop down lists permanent, so when I export a shapefile or bring it back into QGIS, the drop down lists remain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to save the style for this layer and load it when you will load your shapefile back to your QGIS project.

- To save the style: right click on the `Layer` -> `Export` -> `Save as QGIS Layer Style File`
- Import style saved in previous step: `Layer properties` -> `Symbology` -> `Layer styling` -> `Style` -> `Load Style`

Or alternatively

- Save layer as geopackage. Then you can save style inside geopackage and use that style as a default. `Layer properties` -> `Symbology` -> `Layer styling` -> `Style` -> `Save as default` -> `Datasource Database`

Just make sure that when saving a style, you also check the `Forms` option. It is checked by default.

[image: Save Layer Style]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide the answer.