# Create a drop down selection form widget in which options are filtered by previous selection in QField

Tags: qfield

I am new to QField. I am trying to create a form to use in QField in which firstly id like to select a type of tree: Maples, Spruces, Pines and so on. The next field should be the different kind of species: Norway spruce, Sitka spruce, Serbian spruce and so on. For this purpose I created an Excel sheet containing all the species I want as options. There seems to be a lot of similar questions but haven't found solution to mine.
Example1: [Choosing multiple options from QGIS Check Box or Value Map for feature attribute?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239348/choosing-multiple-options-from-qgis-check-box-or-value-map-for-feature-attribute?noredirect=1&lq=1) Following this advice i made a list of species but theres nothing about having a previous field narrowing down the options

Comment: Please include links to the "similar questions" that you have seen and describe why their solutions have not helped you.

Comment: Example1:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239348/choosing-multiple-options-from-qgis-check-box-or-value-map-for-feature-attribute?noredirect=1&lq=1 Following this advice i made a list of species but theres nothing about having a previous field narrowing down the options

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: You seem to be looking for the "value relation widget" : https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-3-2-drive-down-lists-aka-value-relation-widget/ this was not implemented in QFIELD at first but I think it is now....